# AttributeError: module 'curses' has no attribute 'cur_set'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

```
import random
import curses


s = curses.initscr()

curses.cur_set(0)

sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()

w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)

w.keypad(1)

w.timeout(100)


snk_x = sw/4

snk_y = sh/2

snake = [

    [snk_y, snk_x],

    [snk_y, snk_x-1],

    [snk_y, snk_x-2]

]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]

w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)


key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:

    next_key = w.getch()

    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:

        curses.endwin()

        quit()


    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:

        new_head[0] += 1

    if key == curses.KEY_UP:

        new_head[0] -= 1

    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:

        new_head[0] -= 1

    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:

        new_head[0] += 1


    snake.insert(0, new_head)


    if snake[0] == food:

        food = None

        while food is None:

            nf = [random.randint(1, sh-1),

                  random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]

            food = nf if nf not in snake else None

        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

    else:

        tail = snake.pop()

        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], '')


    w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curses` doesn't have a `cur_set()` method, but `curs_set()`.

```
curses.curs_set(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing that out. However, now i am getting--------


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Software/Pycharm (IT310)/Installation/PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.1/first.py", line
 1, in <module>
    from curses import ACS_PI
ImportError: cannot import name 'ACS_PI'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @bonysany Try moving `from curses import ACS_...` after `curses.initscr()`